how to get history of the snowflake table and how to get what is the version of the snowflake table and operation of the snowflake table as well
 select max(timestamp) from (DESCRIBE HISTORY <tablename> ) where operation = 'MERGE'


 DESCRIBE HISTORY <tablename> ).orderBy(col("version").desc).first.getLong(0) 

I need to convert above 2 SQL statement into Snowflake SQL to use in Snowpark code.
I need to get exact output what the above lines of code getting in Spark.

To check the DDL history of the table you can use the commond "SHOW TABLES HISTORY".
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test_show_tables_history(fld1 NUMBER);

DROP TABLE test_show_tables_history;
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test_show_tables_history(fld2 NUMBER);
SHOW TABLES HISTORY LIKE 'test_show_tables_history';

